# Search array element in a file?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array from a file.txt.

I want to loop through the list and check if each element exists in myfile.txt. If the element exists, go to the next element. If it does not exist I want to add it to the not-found array.

I tried using this code:

```
names = ["baba", "lily", "joe", "tsaki"]
names_not_found = []
for i in 0..names.length
 while line = file.gets
     puts if File.open('myfile.txt').lines.any?{|line| line.include?('names') << names_not_found}
    end
    end
    puts names_not_found
            end
```

I'm not to sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: You wrote a Ruby code with *Pythonic way*...:)

Comment: *with this arraylist i want to loop through the list* - which list ? *check if each element exist in myfile.txt,* - *each element* from where ? Lots of confusions I have.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit confused by the other 2 answers, as I thought you wanted to find the elements of your `names` Array that are not found in `myfile.txt`. My answer will find those names. The other solutions find lines of `myfile.txt` that are not equal to any of your `names` elements. There certainly is some misunderstanding, so my apologies if this is not what you want.

You can read the whole file into a String once, and simply use `.include?` (which you already use) to see which names are mentioned in it. Note this simply checks for substrings, so if the file contains a `"joey"` it will "find" `"joe"` because it's part of it. So you might want to use regular expressions with word boundaries, but I suppose that's beyond the scope somewhat.

```
names = ["baba", "lily", "joe", "tsaki"]
contents = File.read('myfile.txt')
names_not_found = names.reject { |name| contents.include? name }
# => ["baba"]

# contents of myfile.txt:
# hello lily
# joe
# tsaki!!
# panda
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do as below:

```
csv_class_names = File.readlines("css_file")
js_file_string = File.read('js_file')
names_not_found = csv_class_names.reject { |class| js_file_string.include?(class.chomp) }  
puts names_not_found
```

Comment: This does not seem correct. You select lines from the file which are identical to one of the names. So for one thing it will show names that ARE in the file, and ONLY if a line is exactly equal to a name.

Comment: still though, you select *lines* rather than the names of the people. If a line is `"planet earth"` it would be part of the `names_not_found` since none of the names is equal to it....... You have to return names that are not present in the file.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers OP is referring to elements in a file and elements in a List not names in particular, am I missing something

Comment: Perhaps I am also misunderstanding his case :)

Comment: I think maybe i was not clear. here is my scenario. i open a css file and get a list of all classes names, then loop through all classes names and try to find them in a javascript file, if the class name is not found i must add it to a not found array.

Comment: @bjhaid i will try your example will tell u what results i get, and when i look at your code it looks like you are not looping through the classes found thanks